Refreshing Listview items ignores background color bindings MAUI
I have a listview in a Grid and I use a binding in the item template to set the background color for the row(s) for the item;
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="10"
                      BackgroundColor="{Binding backColor}"
                      >

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

I also have a couple of Radio buttons to select either All Jobs, or just my jobs.

On the entry to the form all is displayed perfectly. The initial display would show just 'my jobs' If I click the radio button for all jobs (or vice versa), the code will do the following;

1. DO a Listview.SelectedItems.Clear()
2. Clear the underlying data definition (ObservableCollection<Job> jobs)  that the listview uses.
3. Repopulate jobs appropriatly (all/mine) - including setting the backcolor element in the jobs class to the alternating backcolor Blue/Pink
4. set listview.ItemsSource=null;
5. set Listview.ItemsSource to newly populate jobs list.

The good news is the data displayed is correct.
The bad news is that the listview has ignored the bindings for the background color - everything has a background color of white.

Obviously one of the steps I have done when I want to 'refresh' my listview is incorrect (or I have missed a step). 

Wonder if anyone can advise

Stan

I have tried with the following lines commented out
    JobListView.ItemsSource = null;
    JobListView.ItemsSource = jobs;

No observable difference

Where is your ListView? Where is backColor coming from? Is the backColor an observable property?

OK found the solution - got the idea of what to check from reading some 'slightly' related notes.
Originally, I had a global list of jobs - hence I never actually changed the list when I did a refresh of the data - the Listview was always bound to the same list!
Took away the Global list and in the refresh code a new list....
ObservableCollection jobs = new ObservableCollection();
Populated the data and all worked fine - background color came up correctly.
